# How to use CSRF token in e2e testing?

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, angularjs-e2e, mean.io

We are doing a project in MEAN.io, we use CSRF token for authorization for naviagation. Now we decided to automate test the project but we are getting forbidden error while running test cases for POST method, we are not authorized to access the URL from outside because of CSRF. how can we pass the CSRF token through the test case.

sample Test Case code:

```
describe('POST /signin', function () {

// ...
var session;
var csrfToken;


beforeEach(function (done) {
    session.get('/signin')
        .end(function (err, res) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            csrfToken = extractCsrfToken(res);
            done();
        });
});

it('should accept the result', function (done) {
    session
        .post('/signin')
        .send({
            _csrf: csrfToken,
            username: 'foo',
            password: 'bar'
        })
        .expect(201)
        .end(done)
});
// ...
});
```

Comment: Check the sample test code.

Comment: And some explanation! We are suppose to know what this session means in Protractor context? I see Node.js code, not Protractor one.